# Technical Language Usage: Verb for an Equivalence Relationship "Forgetting" an Attribute that is "Modded Away"

Tags: education, equivalence-relations

This question is one of English usage, but I'm sure only mathematicians can answer it for me.

I want to say in a technical report that an attribute is "ignored" or "forgotten" by an equivalence modulo that attribute. The specific example: the [Hopf Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration) clumps all points on the 3-sphere $\mathbb{S}^3$ into equivalence classes of points $(z_1,\,z_2)$ that differ from one another by "phase only", *i.e.* modulo a common scaling by a point on the unit circle, *i.e*

$$(z_1,\,z_2) \sim (z_1^\prime,\,z_2^\prime) \Leftrightarrow \exists \phi\in\mathbb{R}\ni z_1^\prime=z_1\,e^{i\,\phi}, \,z_2^\prime=z_2\,e^{i\,\phi}$$

I'm seeking a sentence like the "Hopf map is modding away common phases", but that's my inner three year old coining a new verb from a noun - can people tell me similar phrase that has known usage? Surprisingly, I have not read the idea expressed in this way (a verb to describe an equivalence relation actively "forgetting" an attribute that is "modded away").

This is a report not meant for mathematicians, but rather for a mathematically literate audience whom I am trying to get across the the idea to of the Hopf map as the minimum complexity and precise tool for forgetting common phases.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain if this is what you want, but you could try "The Hopf Map *identifies* points differing only by phase"

Comment: @MiloBrandt Not at all bad. Particularly if I preface it with something like "mathematicians call this process of clumping identification, and the Hopf map identifies ...". And indeed I have read this usage many times before, it's simply that I couldn't put my finger on it in this context.

Comment: In this connection I've also seen "quotient" as a verb ("*quotiented* out").